# copying and pasting a Windows 7 folder containing a running executable and files it is accessing

Tags: windows-7

On Windows 7, if I copy/paste a folder containing a running executable, will it copy the executable and any files it has open or locked?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking whether you can copy a running executable and locked files and paste them somewhere else, you can. You cannot modify or delete locked or running files, but you can copy them.

Comment: Thank you. Windows copy/paste uses some kind of shadow volume copy? Because I have a backup program that doesn't support it and if I save a file it backups, the same time, it attempts to backup it, it fails to backup it.

Comment: Yeah, I've had problems with backup programs on running programs. Using a windows copy command, though, has worked for me in every case that I remember.

Comment: Writing to a file while reading it is something else than reading an executable that is currently running.